# How to change app language at runtime for Storyboard strings?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to implement language switcher which will change app language without app restart. Found a solution for text inside code, basically a replacement for NSLocalizedString macro, but there is also text inside storyboard in Main.strings, which is not affected. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think u use `Localization` helper class to change the whole application language without restart and change whole device language.

Comment: @IIesh where can I find the Localization helper class?

Comment: The like is https://sites.google.com/site/99classroomdiscussion/assignments/localizeiosapplication  and also contain the both .h and .m files

Comment: it's doesn't solve my problem, storyboard texts are still not affected

Comment: @Minas Have got any solution? I am looking for same

Comment: @Shreyank I simply removed texts from storyboard and set them in code with the micro